# Text area is not accepting characters more than 1959 characters in ASP.net mvc5

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a text area in one of my pages and i have set the maxlength to 2000 characters. Also the same field in database have the data type of nvarchar(max)
But still whenever i am trying to type more than 1959 characters, its showing

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Tried to run the application after removing the maxlength and removing the validations also. But still its not accepting more than characters.

Anybody is there to help me on this

Comment: I don't think it likes the "<". Do you have a tag that isn't closed somewhere? Or maybe you need to try encoding your text area?

Comment: @dkiefer if there is any tag is not closed then why this exception is coming only after 1959 characters? :(

Comment: Are you using that character in the text area?

Answer (score -1):

Here's the code i use for text input, this works fine

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)] 
public ActionResult NewPost(string contenttext, string preview, string postname, string visbl, string posttype, string lang, string friendlyname)
{
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        Post post = new Post();
        post.Language = lang;
        post.FriendlyName = friendlyname;
        post.Post_Date = DateTime.Now;
        post.Preview = preview;
        post.Post_Title = postname;
        post.ID_Post = Guid.NewGuid();                
        post.Active = Boolean.Parse(visbl);                
        post.Post1 = contenttext;
        post.Post_Type = posttype;
        using (TurricanSiteEntities1 datacontext = new TurricanSiteEntities1())
        {
            datacontext.Posts.Add(post);
            try
            { 
                datacontext.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Edp", "Admin");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return View(ex.ToString());
            }
        }                             
    }

    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

Comment: This really has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Are you sure? He is asking to avoid character limitation. This code works to post without character limit.